# How To Use A React Page For a Github Domain Page

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I seem to be having some trouble with Github. I would like to update the master branch, which is my old io_page, with a new io_page. My only problem now is that the page will not show the new_io page. I've tried using the build file several times (the new_io page is built in react) but the page doesn't work on the master branch. However, it previously worked on the gh-pages branch. I also set the homepage in the package.json to the domain name that I'm using.

My GitHub: https://github.com/Taniyah-L-Jackson/Taniyah-L-Jackson.github.io

What is currently showing: https://taniyah-l-jackson.github.io/

My package.json file:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://taniyah-l-jackson.github.io/",
  "name": "cra-io-page",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "gh-pages": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you build the project and then deployed it?

Comment: Yes, but the build doesnt seem to work on the master branch

Answer (score 0):

Update: The page is working now. I had to change the scripts from

```
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

to

```
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",
```

and then re-deploy the build

Reference: https://medium.com/swlh/deploying-react-apps-to-github-pages-on-master-branch-creating-a-user-site-bc96c2a37dc8